# Memory Debugging tools for visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have several heap corruption problems with an application I am working on. It is built on C and we are using Visual Studio to compile and debug it. But we have this annoying heap corruptions problem and we need to find the source of that corruption.

Do you know any good tool that can help me? I have already tried purify plus but it is giving me some problems.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has a suite of [heap debugging tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx) built in. Compiling with [/ANALYZE](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/adventures-with-analyze-for-visual-studiothe-good/) helps too.

Answer (score 2):

Application Verifier should be your go-to tool for heap corruption on Windows. I've written about it here:

http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/increased-reliability-through-more-crashes/